# local variable 'like' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-errors

I get the following error when I try to load the page: `local variable 'like' referenced before assignment`. It traces back to `"like": like,` in my context.

Could someone please help me fix this?

Thank you!

***views.py:***

```
def photo_detail(request, photo_slug):
    photos = Photo.objects.filter(slug=photo_slug)
    obj = get_object_or_404(Photo, slug=photo_slug)
    all_comments = obj.comment_set.all()
    truncate_amount = 3
    display_comments = obj.comment_set.all()[:int(truncate_amount)]
    for c in all_comments:
        c.get_children()
    comment_form = CommentForm()

    try: 
        like = Like.objects.get(pk=obj.id)
    except Like.DoesNotExist:
    pass

    context = {
        "all_comments": all_comments,
        "comment_form": comment_form,
        "display_comments": display_comments,
        "like": like,
        "obj": obj,
        "photos": photos,
        "truncate_amount": truncate_amount
    }
    return render(request, "photos/photo_detail.html", context)
```

Comment: You should remove the line `photos = Photo.objects.filter(slug=photo_slug)`  as you don't use `photos` afterward. What are you trying to achieve with `like = Like.objects.get(pk=obj.id)`? `obj.id` is the id of a `Photo` object, you cannot use it to retrieve a `Like` object. I guess what you are trying to do is something like `Like.objects.get(photo=obj)`, maybe post your models so we can help you more.

Comment: Thank you @aumo for your input! I changed the line to `Like.objects.get(photo=obj)`. I kept `photos = Photo.objects.filter(slug=photo_slug)` because I use it later in my html template to display the images.

Comment: Is not `photo_slug` a unique field? If it is, all that `photos` will ever contain is a list containing a single element which is `obj`.

Comment: @aumo I see what you are saying now. I had the element in a for loop (stupid, I know). I corrected that error. Thank you for looking out for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a `Like.DoesNotExist` exception, you just `pass`, without assigning anything to `like`. But then you try to use it anyway. Hence the error telling you that you tried to use it before assigning anything to it.

If you want to assign some "fallback" value, like `None`, you can do that explicitly:

```
try: 
    like = Like.objects.get(pk=obj.id)
except Like.DoesNotExist:
    like = None
```

Comment: @jape It does not fail anymore but your code is still not right, the `like` variable will never contain the right value, see my comment on your question for infos.